# how to extract data for coordinates from SpatRaster class in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get monthly climate data for a list of coordinates. I'm aware of a method to get bioclim variables from worldclim outlined here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227585/using-r-to-extract-data-from-worldclim, which I have been able to reproduce sucessfully. I'm also interested in getting monthly data, which should be possible with the worldclim_tile function in the geodata R package, but I haven't been successful.

I've created a list of example coordinates below.

```
longs <- c(-75,-80,-85)
lats <- c(40,42,44)
coords <- data.frame(x=longs,y=lats)
```

I then download minimum temperature monthly data with worldclim_tile and keep month 5 (I'm only interested in May data.

```
test <- worldclim_tile(lon=longs[1], lat=lats[1], var="tmin", res=0.5, version="2.1", path = tempdir())
test <- test[[5]]

> test
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 3600, 3600, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent      : -90, -60, 30, 60  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : tile_16_wc2.1_30s_tmin.tif 
name        : tile_16_wc2.1_30s_tmin_5 
min value   :                     -9.2 
max value   :                     20.4
```

I thought getting tmin data for my coordinate list should be possible using SpatialPonits of the sp package if the coordinates are contained in "coord. ref", but this produces an error:

```
points <- SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = "test@coord. ref.")
values <- extract(test,points)

"Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'obj' in selecting a method for function 'bbox': assignment of an object of class “character” is not valid for slot ‘proj4string’ in an object of class “Spatial”; is(value, "CRS") is not TRUE"
```

I'm not sure where to go from here and I haven't found any useful examples in the documentation of the geodata  or  sp package. Does anyone know of a method to get the data for these coordinates?

It also may be problematic that "coord. ref." has a space, so I would be interested in renaming that if it is possible as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `geodata` and `terra` packages. The trick to use `worldclim_tile` is to indicate a pair of coordinates (lon, lat) to download the worldclim data. Afterward, instead of trying to convert your `coords` object into a `SpatialPoints` object, you can use `vect` to convert it into a `SpatVector`, which is the type of objects `terra` uses to work with vector data. Here you just need to indicate the names of the x and y columns used to create the `SpatVector` object, as well as its crs (I assumed the data corresponded to geographic coordinates in WGS84, i.e., `"EPSG:4326"`). Finally, you can use `extract` to get the desired output.

```
# Load required libraries
library(geodata)
library(terra)

# Download data using geodata package
test <- worldclim_tile("tmin",
                       coords[1,1],
                       coords[1,2],
                       path = "WorldClimData")

# Subset data: layer 5
test <- test[[5]]

# Convert data frame to vector object
points <- vect(coords,
               geom=c("x", "y"),
               crs = "EPSG:4326")
# Extract values
values <- extract(test,
                  points)

#  ID tile_16_wc2.1_30s_tmin_5
#1  1                     10.6
#2  2                      7.2
#3  3                      5.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just with `{raster}` package:

```r
[...]
raster::extract(test, coords)
#>   ID tile_16_wc2.1_30s_tmin_5
#> 1  1                     10.6
#> 2  2                      7.2
#> 3  3                      5.4
```

There is no need to convert df with coordinates to `vect` class for `{terra}` as `extract()` has the method for matrix and data.frame as well:

```r
terra::extract(test, coords)
#>   ID tile_16_wc2.1_30s_tmin_5
#> 1  1                     10.6
#> 2  2                      7.2
#> 3  3                      5.4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for sharing this modification to the above method, I've used it in my solution.