# R geodata package: NAs for coordinates using worldclim_tile

Tags: r

I used the example code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76623171/how-to-extract-data-for-coordinates-from-spatraster-class-in-r) to download WorldClim temperature averages for a set of coordinates, but a lot of my coordinates are coming up with NAs. Previously, I successfully downloaded data for these coordinates using getData from the raster/sp packages, but I'm trying to switch over to the geodata package. Here's my code:

```
library(geodata)
library(terra)

df1 <- data.frame(x = c(92.892780,104.016700, 104.166700, 137.608100, 18.816670, -50.333330), # long
                  y = c(34.728610, 32.983330, 33.033330, 36.561600, 68.350000, 67.113330)) # lat

test <- worldclim_tile("tavg",
                        df1[1,1],
                        df1[1,2],
                        version="2.1",
                        path="WorldClimData")
points <- vect(df1,
                geom=c("x", "y"),
                crs = "EPSG:4326")
values <- extract(test,
                   points)

> values
 ID tile_22_wc2.1_30s_tavg_1 tile_22_wc2.1_30s_tavg_2 tile_22_wc2.1_30s_tavg_3 tile_22_wc2.1_30s_tavg_4
1  1                    -17.1                    -15.0                    -10.5                     -5.7
2  2                    -10.1                     -8.1                     -4.4                      0.1
3  3                     -5.0                     -2.6                      1.7                      6.5
4  4                       NA                       NA                       NA                       NA
5  5                       NA                       NA                       NA                       NA
6  6                       NA                       NA                       NA                       NA
```

As you can see, some of the coordinates return the needed data, while others don't. I'd like to figure out how to get the data downloaded for all coordinates.

Using R version 2022.07.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `worldclim_tile` the downloaded data will only include areas around the lat and lon indicated. For downloading larger areas you can use `worldclim_country` or `worldclim_global`. Since your data include areas quite apart, I suggest using `worldclim_global`. In this function you just need to indicate the resolution in minutes of a degree.

```
test <- worldclim_global("tavg",
                         res = 10,
                         version="2.1",
                         path="WorldClimData")
```